# Android Contacts RAW_CONTACT_ID vs CONTACT_ID

Tags: android, contacts

I am using a contact picker as follows:

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT)
```

What I want to know is whether the last path segment of the returned URI is the `CONTACT_ID` or the `RAW_CONTACT_ID`.

In case it is the `CONTACT_ID`, how do I retrieve all `RAW_CONTACT_ID`s from this contact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get CONTACT_ID as the return data.

In case if you need to get the list of all the RAW_CONTACT_ID of the contact here is what you can include in

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {       
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if ((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)){

         Uri contactData = data.getData(); 
         // This gives the value of Contact URI                  
         Cursor c =  managedQuery(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,  new String[] {RawContacts._ID}, RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = " +  contactData.getLastPathSegment(), null, null); 
         // This query would give you list of Raw_COntact_ID for the added contact
     }
}
```

Comment: what we have to pass as "data"?

Comment: "data"  (Intent) would be returned from ContactPicker. I have formatted the answer properly. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you **need** to use the `CONTACT_ID` ?

Otherwise, I recommend you use `LOOKUP_KEY` instead.

See [1](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) and [2](http://dev.schmid.pro/android/get-contacts-on-android-2-0)