# return raw_contact_id or contacts_id ? contacts api in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

in the Contacts API, there is a difference between querying a contact in the `RawContact` table, and in the `Contacts` table (as shown below : `Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID`or `Data.CONTACT_ID`) :
in which case can i retrieve the contact id, and in which other case will i retrieve a raw_contact id?
for example, if we want to pick a contact, will it return the raw_contact_id or the contact_id of my query?

Here's the code from the doc :

```
Query
Finding all Data of a given type for a given contact

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
          new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
          Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                  + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
          new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);

Finding all Data of a given type for a given raw contact

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
          new String[] {Data._ID, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone.LABEL},
          Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                  + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'",
          new String[] {String.valueOf(rawContactId)}, null);
```

Thanks

Comment: this issue has been discussed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302279/android-contacts-raw-contact-id-vs-contact-id

Comment: @elijah : thanks, i did not see this subject, thanks for posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Data._ID or Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, both of them refer to the same contact.
ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.CONTACT_ID also is same as Data._ID